# RegEx from PCRE engine does not matches with RegEx with Pandas

Tags: regex, pandas

So I have a pandas series like below

```
test_urls = pd.Series([
 'https://www.amazon.com/Technology-Ventures-Enterprise-Thomas-Byers/dp/0073523429',
 'http://www.interactivedynamicvideo.com/',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/07/movies/07stein.html?_r=0',
 'http://evonomics.com/advertising-cannot-maintain-internet-heres-solution/',
 'HTTPS://github.com/keppel/pinn',
 'Http://phys.org/news/2015-09-scale-solar-youve.html',
 'https://iot.seeed.cc',
 'http://www.bfilipek.com/2016/04/custom-deleters-for-c-smart-pointers.html',
 'http://beta.crowdfireapp.com/?beta=agnipath',
 'https://www.valid.ly?param',
 'http://css-cursor.techstream.org'
])
```

To capture only the domains, I have used the below regex expression from PCRE:
`(?<=\/\/)(\w+[-.]?\w+[.]?){2}`

Now when I use this in Pandas, below unexpected result is inferenced:

```
test_urls_clean = test_urls.str.extract(r"(?<=\/\/)(\w+[-.]?\w+[.]?){2}", expand=False)
    0
0   com
1   com
2   com
3   om
4   om
5   rg
6   cc
7   com
8   com
9   ly
10  techstream.org
```

But using the below regex, correct results are fetched
`https?://([\w\-\.]+)`

Any reason why this issue happens with Pandas?

Comment: Please also include exactly what you _want_ to match here, as this is not entirely clear.

Comment: Are you asking *why* different regular expression dialects exist?

Comment: Yes. Different regular expression dialects exist, and functionality, syntax and features vary between them. That's why the issue happens.

Comment: That seems to be the result with pcre as well. Please include the way you are testing PCRE.

Comment: I am trying to get the domain out of the list of URLs. So when I use `(?<=\/\/)(\w+[-.]?\w+[.]?){2}` in PCRE it retrieves the domain, but when used with pandas, only the last part of domain, e.g.,'com' is retrieved. I want to know why this issue occurs. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly...

The first regex `(?<=\/\/)(\w+[-.]?\w+[.]?){2}` is **matching** the url, but only **capturing** the TLD.

So `.com` etc. is the only part returned when using `str.extract` (*extract the captured group only*).

See https://regex101.com/r/aMKgFv/1 and notice the blue (match) vs the green (capture) in the highlighting of the urls.

---

**Additional:**

For getting the domain out of the string I would recommend avoiding regex and let `urllib` do the work.

**Code:**

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import pandas as pd
    
def getDomain(s):
    return urlparse(s).netloc

test_urls = pd.Series([
 'https://www.amazon.com/Technology-Ventures-Enterprise-Thomas-Byers/dp/0073523429',
 'http://www.interactivedynamicvideo.com/',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/07/movies/07stein.html?_r=0',
 'http://evonomics.com/advertising-cannot-maintain-internet-heres-solution/',
 'HTTPS://github.com/keppel/pinn',
 'Http://phys.org/news/2015-09-scale-solar-youve.html',
 'https://iot.seeed.cc',
 'http://www.bfilipek.com/2016/04/custom-deleters-for-c-smart-pointers.html',
 'http://beta.crowdfireapp.com/?beta=agnipath',
 'https://www.valid.ly?param',
 'http://css-cursor.techstream.org'
])

test_urls = test_urls.apply(getDomain)

print(test_urls)

0                      www.amazon.com
1     www.interactivedynamicvideo.com
2                     www.nytimes.com
3                       evonomics.com
4                          github.com
5                            phys.org
6                        iot.seeed.cc
7                    www.bfilipek.com
8               beta.crowdfireapp.com
9                        www.valid.ly
10          css-cursor.techstream.org
dtype: object
```